# [iOS]Can I change the size of a freeform UIViewController on code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I want to change the size of `UIViewController` whose size has already set in `storyboard` as `freeform`.
I need to remove some `subview`s after I get a certain result from a server.
Originally the size is 320x750 but it sometimes will be reduced to 320x500.

I use autolayout.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove autolayout and then use

```
   setPreferredContentSize:(CGSize)
```

If you want to keep autolayout, you'll have to programatically add constraints.